# How to update a row in a table in Wordpress

Tags: wpdb

I have a table of data rows. Now I want to click on the Update button then that row of data will be Updated based on the ID

Here is my demo:

[image]

These are my commands:

```
<?php
              foreach ($get_data as $infocontact) {
                    echo '<form class="form-info-wmtp" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_image" id="id_image" value="'.$infocontact->id.'" />';
                    echo '<div class="txt-info-wmtp">'.$infocontact->button_name.'<p><input type="text" value="'.$infocontact->link_button.'" name="link_button" placeholder="Enter the link button">';
                    echo '<input type="submit" id="btnSubmitSocial" name="btnSubmitSocial" value="Update">';
                    echo '<input type="submit" id="delete-btn" name="btnDelete" value="Delete"></p></div>';
                }
                echo '</form>';

                if(isset($_POST['btnSubmitSocial'])){
                    $link = $_POST['link_button'];
                    $id_img = $_POST['id_image'];
                    var_dump($id_img);

                    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'call_button';
                    $post_data=array(
                        'link_button' => $link,
                        'id' => $id_img
                    );

                    $wpdb->update( $table, $post_data, array( 'id' => $id_img ), $format = null, $where_format = null );
                }

            ?>
```

I'm stuck here for hours, please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Move `echo '</form>';` inside the `foreach`, so that  each row is its own form. At the moment all the fields are going into one form, which is preventing your code from working because there will be multiple IDs. As long as you've got the table name/structure correct, I don't see any other issue.

Comment: Wow, It worked. Thank you so much, I've been sitting with that problem for hours without finding a fault, you helped me fix it quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pull form closing tag inside foreach loop

```
<?php
foreach ($get_data as $infocontact) {
        echo '<form class="form-info-wmtp" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_image" id="id_image" value="'.$infocontact->id.'" />';
        echo '<div class="txt-info-wmtp">'.$infocontact->button_name.'<p><input type="text" value="'.$infocontact->link_button.'" name="link_button" placeholder="Enter the link button">';
        echo '<input type="submit" id="btnSubmitSocial" name="btnSubmitSocial" value="Update">';
        echo '<input type="submit" id="delete-btn" name="btnDelete" value="Delete"></p></div>';
        //i pull /form inside loop here
        echo '</form>';
}

if(isset($_POST['btnSubmitSocial'])){
   $link = $_POST['link_button'];
   $id_img = $_POST['id_image'];
   var_dump($id_img);

   $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'call_button';
   $post_data=array(
   'link_button' => $link,
   'id' => $id_img
   );

   $wpdb->update( $table, $post_data, array( 'id' => $id_img ), $format = null, $where_format = null );
}
?>
```